# Problems connecting Debian to Windows SMB share using smbclient?

Tags: linux, debian, smb, smbclient

I'm having problems connecting my Debian Linux system to my Windows SMB share.

The other windows VMs have no problem mounting the drive, just Linux.

- This VM is connected to the AD by realmd, and using sssd.

**The ERROR -**

```
gensec_spnego_client_negTokenInit_step: gse_krb5: creating NEG_TOKEN_INIT for cifs/windows-2016-dc failed (next[(null)]): NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
```

**What I've done so far**

Installed samba, samba-common samba-client

mkdir /mnt/smb

Within the /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
workgroup = MYSERVER.ads.com
```

Right at the bottom

```
[smb]
comment = SMB
path = /mnt/smb
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0666
directory mask = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
valid users = @admin, @staff, @developer
```

sudo service smbd restart

test parm

sudo smbclient "//windows-2016-dc/SMB" -U administrator

Comment: `winbind` or `sssd`?

Comment: Sorry i'm using sssd

Comment: I can't get sssd to interoperate with samba. I've gone back to using winbind

Comment: You cannot use sssd with Samba >= 4.8.0 and shares, you must use winbind. Also, you cannot use 'guest ok = yes' with 'valid users'

Comment: Please clarify the topic - *connecting my Debian Linux system to my Windows SMB share* seems either nonsense or confusing as you are installing Samba which offers file services, thus it seems *Windows SMB share* means your Samba share.